# Generating tables in LaTeX - Errors

Tags: tables

I would like to generate the table shown below in LaTeX (with only top , middle and bottom! rules) and no cell dividers. 
Here is my MWE.I get many errors.What is the problem here?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{CCC}
\toprule
Parameters & Linux & Windows
\midrule
Number of users & Linux have a plus point that many users can be logged into the system\\ simultaneously.SSH (Secure Shell security) is used in this process.ThisProcessor’s capability is distributed amongst the users. In this way various users can access the resources at the same time. & There are many windows operating systems considered as single user and multi user. Windows XP, 7 are single user. Multi user comprises of Windows NT.There can be many users logged in the operating system but only one can use it at a time.
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the corrected code. I have commented changes in it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{LLL}
\toprule
Parameters & Linux & Windows\\  %% missing \\
\midrule
Number of users & Linux have a plus point that many users can be logged into the system %% no need of \\
                  simultaneously.SSH (Secure Shell security)is used in this process. This Processor’s 
                  capability is distributed amongst the users.In this way various users can access the 
                  resources at the same time. 
                  & There are many windows operating systems 
                  considered as single user and multi user. Windows XP, 7 are single user. 
                  Multi user comprises of Windows NT.There can be many users logged in the 
                  operating system but only one can use it at a time. \\ %% missing \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The OP used [CCC] which is not defined and `\\` are missing at the end of a row. For line break in a cell, you need `\newline`.

Or use of `tabularx` with X column. the table width can be determined by user and X column is like a paragraph setting that will automatically determine its column width given the width of the table.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{XXX}
\toprule
Parameters & Linux & Windows\\
\midrule
Number of users & Linux have a plus point that many users can be logged into the system\newline simultaneously.SSH (Secure Shell security) is used in this process.ThisProcessor's capability is distributed amongst the users. In this way various users can access the resources at the same time. & There are many windows operating systems considered as single user and multi user. Windows XP, 7 are single user. Multi user comprises of Windows NT.There can be many users logged in the operating system but only one can use it at a time.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```